# How to load common templates globally?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I've been loading common templates like header and footer in my controllers:

```
public function load_store_home_page($storeName) {
    //Assign the page title
    $global_data['page_title'] = $storeName;

//Load the header
$global_data['header'] = $this->load->view('header','', true);

    ...
```

But I'm doing this in every controller function. It seems messy. Is there a way I can somehow load these common elements globally?

Comment: why are you putting it in $global_data?

Comment: Create a custom controller extend CI_Controller and as @kristian said, override __construct and __deconstruct.  That way when you need a page with a header and footer you can just use that custom controller, if you don't want the header and footer you can just use the regular controller.

Comment: it's for layout...http://joshhighland.com/blog/2008/11/09/how-i-do-layouts-and-views-in-codeigniter/ - I'm loading some data that's specific to the page in to nested templates and these templates get loaded in to a global view. $global_data are bits I want to load directly in to this global view

Comment: I guess the naming convention through me off, but i see what you're doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this, as there are occasions when you don't want to include neither a header nor a footer, due to redirects, sending files, json data or similiar. Instead, what I do, is simply that I include header and footer from the view itself.

However, if you insist, I suppose you could load the views from your classes constructor `__construct()` and deconstructor `__deconstruct()`.

Comment: How do I include the header directly from the view? This sounds like a good solution to me.

Comment: From your view, you just include `<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>` in the beginning of the file, and ditto in the end of the file.

Comment: like this  <? $this->load->view('header'); ?>

Comment: @elduderino Yes, just like that.